# C# DataGridView data-bound error with Grid.Rows.Add method

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview, datatable

i have a DataGridView on the Form. I select some data from database and load them to datatable and after that i make reference this datatable to grid's datasorurce as below.

```
string sql = "";
sql = "SELECT id,name,surname,code FROM t_persons";
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
...
adapter.Fill(dt);
grid.DataSource = dt;
```

and after that i want to add new row to this grid with **grid.Rows.Add()** method. But every time it gives an error **Rows cannot be programmatically added to the DataGridView's rows collection when the control is data-bound.**
So whatis the problem and how can i solve it.

Comment: Solve it by adding a row to the `DataTable` (isn't the exception self-explanatory?).

Comment: You can add rows to DataTable instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add row to the DataTable, not to the DataGridView. That is what the exception is saying. Try:

```
DataRow newRow = dt.NewRow();
dt.Rows.Add(newRow);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please you can add row directly to datatable and it's effect on gridview because it's bind to datatable.