# Copy selected rows and add in datagridview in Winform

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have DataGridView bind with DataTable. I have to do following tasks,
1. GetSelected rows and
2. add same rows in datagridview

First task will be done by method SelectedRows of DataGridView. but when i try to add selected row in datagridview its giving following exception as 
***"Rows cannot be programmatically added to the DataGridView's rows collection when the control is data-bound."***

How to add selected rows in DataGridView even if dataTable bind to datagridview.Your any pointer will be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not add the rows to the DataTable instead? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12088042/c-sharp-datagridview-data-bound-error-with-grid-rows-add-method

Comment: Maybe try to perform `Refresh` after you add rows to your DataTable

Comment: Yes.I will add row to DataTable. But how to access selected rows data as its DataGridViewRow and set this values in new DataRow.